# Где нужно инициализировать MongoDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mongodb

Например, я хочу создать индексы для коллекции. Где я это должен делать, в DbContext? Он будет часто инициализироваться и каждый раз создавать индексы, да ещё и не асинхронно - такое себе.

```
public class AuditDbContext : IAuditDbContext
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly IMongoDatabase _database;

    #endregion

    #region Entities

    public IMongoCollection<AuditEntry> AuditEntries => _database.GetCollection<AuditEntry>("AuditEntries");

    #endregion

    #region Ctor

    public AuditDbContext(DatabaseItem settings)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString);
        _database = client.GetDatabase("audit");
        InitializeDatabase();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void InitializeDatabase()
    {
        var auditEntryBuilder = Builders<AuditEntry>.IndexKeys;
        AuditEntries.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<AuditEntry>(auditEntryBuilder.Ascending(x => x.EntityTypeName)));
        AuditEntries.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<AuditEntry>(auditEntryBuilder.Ascending("Properties.PropertyName")));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: причем тут конекст. Если вам надо запустить одноразово, то для этого есть миграции. Если при каждом старте приложения надо запкскать - для этого есть `Startup`

Comment: Если такой индекс уже есть, новый не будет строиться. Можно каждый раз "создавать"

Comment: @tym32167 у монго нет миграций

Comment: @TotalPusher да, я понимаю, просто это время занимает, 1-2 секунды иногда

Comment: Тогда нужно написать JS скрипт создания индексов и положить его в автозагрузку системы. Вы сами себе ответьте на вопрос: вы создали индексы, они слетели (почему?), как их восстановить? Или на вопрос: ставится на голую систему, как создать индексы (добавить в скрипт установки создание индексов)?

Comment: @TotalPusher инициализация и подразумевает один раз создать. Мне это нужно, когда сервер будет на проде разворачиваться, чтобы не нужно было вручную создавать индексы.

Comment: Тогда либо вручную, либо любой инструмент Continuous integration

Comment: Не стесняйтесь давать ответы